# How to uppercase one thing but leave the other one none case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
select invoice_number, invoice_date, invoice_total, invoice_due_date, date_format(invoice_due_date, 'Due in %M %Y') as month_due
from active_invoices

order by invoice_total desc
```

[Here's my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4i8p.png)

How can I make it to look like this?

[Wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyxiC.png)

Comment: i tried Ucase but that uppercased all of them

Comment: Why do you need such output which isn't consistent in case of casing.

Comment: I know what you mean, but thats what my instructor wants

Comment: So the rule is "June should be upper case and July should be not upper" ?

Comment: That is not at all cool. However, what is the logic to uppercase column. I suppose it is like if Month is June than upper case.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.@jon ekiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case statement to filter on June on July and apply different upper case conditions.

```
SELECT invoice_number
    , invoice_date
    , invoice_total
    , invoice_due_date
    , CASE 
        WHEN month(invoice_due_date) = 7
            THEN date_format(invoice_due_date, 'Due in %M %Y')
        WHEN month(invoice_due_date) = 6
            THEN date_format(invoice_due_date, 'DUE IN %M %Y')
        END AS month_due
FROM active_invoices
ORDER BY invoice_total DESC
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @idk_meu added the query

Comment: June didnt get uppercased but i added ucase for that and made it work. Thank you.